# Activities component showing all Account activities on Opportunity record page

Tags: apex, lightning, opportunity, activityhistory, activity-timeline

Typically on an Opportunity record page the Activities standard component will only show activities where the WhatId is the Opportunity.

I'm looking to get this component to behave how it does on the Account page where it grabs all child records and associates all of their activities with the account. So basically I'd like to switch the component on the Opportunity page to use the Parent Account for grabbing activities so a user could easily see the entire history with the Account (and child relationships) from the Opportunity page.

As far as I can tell there are no codeless ways to achieve this. Furthermore, the code for the standard Activities component does not appear to be exposed to the user.

I went looking for packages to achieve this but I haven't found any. The closest I have gotten is this https://github.com/vipultaylor/sf-activity-timeline which is supposed to copy the behavior of the standard component. I think I can edit that code to accomplish what I'm looking to do, but it is old and I am unable to get the package to install. When I try to deploy via sf CLI I get an error ("Unexpected: You should not have arrived here) so I am at a loss.

Does anyone have any thoughts on a solution to accomplish what I'm looking to do? It seems like it should be a common desired use case.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new record page (Setup | User Interface | Lightning App Builder | New). In the wizard, choose a Record Page, give it a name, then clone the standard page layout. From here, use the Related List - Standard component and place it on the layout. Then, choose the Parent Record of Account Name, and the Related List Activities. Once you have this set up, click the Save button, then the Activation option, and finally assign this page as the system default (or another option). Once done, you'll now have a new related list component that shows all activities for the account.

[image: Related List Configuration]